# Which steps to take to remove Display from S/36 (System/36)? And which steps to take to add a Display to S/36?

Tags: display

Because S/36 (System/36) is very old system. It is hard to find a useful guide to help me remove/add a display to the S/36.

Could anybody tell me,

Which steps to take to remove a Display from S/36? And which steps to take to add a Display to S/36?

Best Regards,
Hye-Jin van Dorssen